# DirectX real time textures

Tags: c#, directx, direct3d, screen-capture

I am using C# to with managed Direct3D to create a square. The texture of this square is my desktop (a screen capture). I used Direct3D to take the screenshot (takes 70 milliseconds) then I remake the texture to display on the square (takes 1000 milliseconds).

How can I create textures instantly in Direct3D to have a real time view?
Bellow is how I currently create the texture to use.

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
{
    bitmapData = bmp.LockBits(bounds, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Marshal.Copy(screenData, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, screenData.Length);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    texture = Texture.FromBitmap(d3dDevice, bmp, 0, Pool.SystemMemory);
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what are you trying to achieve. Is your primary goal capturing of the desktop screen and then wrapping it on some 3D mesh/polygon?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Do you need a mipmap? If you're taking the default format, Dx is going to produce a mipmap, which will increase the time to generate the texture as well as the time to push it to the GPU, as it will be much larger.

Out of curiosity, what is the type of screenData?

Answer (score 0):

Via Map/Unmap updating the texture content should be much faster.

I will describe it here for C++ but it should be very similar in C#:

You have to create your texture in a way such as it is CPU accessible:

```
d3dTextureDescription.Usage          = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
d3dTextureDescription.BindFlags  = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
d3dTextureDescription.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
```

Afterwards you can use the `Map` function of your device context to get access to the texture:

```
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE MappedResource;
HRESULT hr = rendererD3D->getImmediateContextD3D()->Map(
        m_pTexture2D,
        mipMapLevel, //0,
        D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD,
        0,
        &MappedResource);

ASSERTEx(hr == S_OK, "Map failed.");

*data = MappedResource.pData;
```

In the next step the data pointer can be used to modify the texture content. If you are done call `Unmap`